# Regex - match whole line if has a specific word and case insensitive with PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a simple regex code to match a whole line in text file that has a specific word. I use PHP function preg_match_all.

this is my regex pattern:

```
$word= 'world';
$contents = '
this is my WoRld
this is my world
this is my wORLD
this is my home
';
$pattern = "/^.*$word.*\$/m";
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);

// results will be in $matches[0]
```

this function get the full line but search for case sensitive only so it will return the second line only of the text.

I want it to match all line (that has "world" word in any form).

I read about using /i but I don't know how to combine it with the pattern above.

I tried:

/^.*$pattern.*\$/m/i

/^.*$pattern.*\$/m/i

/^.*$pattern.*\$/i

Comment: `"/^.*$word.*$/mi"` this should work

Comment: @CodeManiac I try to add / before ^ so I get another error:

Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Yes you don't need to use `g` flag with `preg_match_all`

Comment: @CodeManiac "/^.*$word.*$/mi" this works! please add your comment an answer to set as top answer

Comment: This doesn't add any value to the existing answer present on so, as this was just missing a flag, so i won't be posting an answer, i will link it to already posted answers

Comment: There is no need to include the `$` end of line anchor -- it can be safely omitted from the pattern.  The greedy dot will match to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression,

```
(?i)^.*\bworld\b.*$
```

might simply return those desired strings.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?i)^.*\bworld\b.*$/m';
$str = 'this is my WoRld
this is my world
this is my wORLD
this is my home';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "this is my WoRld"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "this is my world"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "this is my wORLD"
  }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: hello emma and than you for reply! the code work just fine but I don't know know why it takes more time than the old one :/ can you please tell me what to change in the regex code you provide to match world( OR wOrld   ( OR worlD str123 (   .. I mean to match the word with parenthesis after even if there's anything between the word and the parenthesis .. Thank you in advance!

Comment: thank you for reply! I was meaning to match the lines only with:   world( OR wOrld ( OR worlD str123 (    in the string with the same new line condition like the original question :)

Comment: `i` is more simply expressed with `m` after the pattern's ending delimiter.